# .htaccess Configuration adding two forward slashes

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am running a custom PHP MVC system and I am handling some of the normal .htaccess functions inside my PHP to ensure portability of the site but I have run into problems with, guess what? Portability!

I am with NetRegistry in this particular instance and the .htaccess has the following entries:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|txt|gif|jpg|png|css|phtml|json|ogv|mp4|webm)$ index.php [L]
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymlinks
```

My links inside the pages are like so:

```
<a href="/">Home</a>
<a href="AboutUs">About Us</a>
```

Everything works fine except the home page, somewhere two forward slashes are being added to the domain name, but I don't believe that it can be attributed to my .htaccess Apache directives.

I'm adding the base to the url like so:

```
if("" ===trim($urlParams[0])) {
    $includeFile        = BASE_URI.CONTROLLER_DIR."/Index.php";
    $controllerName     = CONTROLLER_PATH."IndexController";
}
```

To see what's happening exactly, the reference site is [Entourage Media](http://www.entouragemedia.com.au).

Can anybody please help me understand this problem ?

Comment: The `.htaccess` doesn't print out that 404 page.

Comment: Try adding the `<base>` tag to your page templates?

Comment: no @mario, it doesn't but I am capturing the  BASE_URL and $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] which outputs http://www.entouragemedia.com.au/// with the two forward slashes

Comment: @hjpotter92 I've edited the details to show how I do that